# How mathutils.Vector.angle() use?

Tags: python, vector

```
a = Vector((1,2,3))
b = Vector((4,3,2))

print(a.angle(b))
```

I'm trying to calculate two vectors' angle between them using Vector_1.angle(Vector_2), but output is None. What kind of format it should be?

[image]

Comment: It is not `None`, it print `0.6533257961273193` in my console

Comment: Why we different @X Y

Comment: Does it make a difference if you run in the blender text editor?

Comment: Oh it work! Maybe there are some mistake in jupyter?

Comment: no idea, I use Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Same with you, I also use VS Code

Comment: Make sure your IDE's python version is the same as blender, then it should work.

Answer (score 3):

The output is not `None`. It is **0.6533257961273193**. Try again use this code:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *

a = Vector((1,2,3))
b = Vector((4,3,2))

print(a.angle(b))
```